# CDI Injection into a Servlet not working

Tags: java, servlets, cdi, session-scope, producer

I have a Controller with a producer.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserController{

    private User user;

    //other methods

    @Produces
    @User
    public User produceUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

If I inject the user into a Servlet, I get always the same user(I compared the object IDs) - also in different sessions. If I inject the User in a CDI Bean, it's working and I get the user of the current session.

Comment: Not very familiar with CDI, but servlets are persisting over many different sessions; you will either need to inject a proxy that selects the current user or inject a UserService

Comment: Please provide more information.  What container are you running? What version of CDI, etc?

Comment: Can you show how you create a User object and the servlet with the injection point?

Answer (score 1):

`UserController` is session-scoped, but the producer is not. I.e. the producer has `@Dependent` scope, so the `User` bean gets injected once when the servlet is initialized.

Try adding `@SessionScoped` to your producer method.